# How to integrate phpBB with yii 2.0

Tags: yii, phpbb, phpbb3

For yii 1.1 ,proper documentation is there but for yii 2.0 they specified nothing.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpbb-integration-kit - for yii 1.1

If any have answer please reply.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/8sun/yii2-integration-phpBB3.1

Comment: please specify steps that i have to follow for integration

Comment: @BhupeshArora I also want to integrate PHPbb with my Yii2 Please help me if you found any solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use that from git - https://github.com/8sun/freestylepoker

And this guide - https://github.com/8sun/freestylepoker#docs-list

Comment: i follow the steps you provide but i not able to integrate yii 2.0 to phpBB 3.1

Comment: Incomplete instructions.